# Is it possible to have different styles for top and bottom WebKit scrollbar buttons?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I want to make a WebKit scrollbar that has different border-radius for top and bottom buttons, like this:

[image: scrollbar]

This is the CSS at the moment for the buttons:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8.5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8.5px;
}
```

but this makes both buttons have curved bottom corners.

Is there a way to do this (preferrably with CSS only)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can differentiate the top and bottom buttons using

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement
```

and

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment
```

---

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8.5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8.5px;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
  border-top-left-radius: 8.5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8.5px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6rgpdbv/)

Comment: Sorry ! removed my comment